# Async images loading on page

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to have users wait. Albums could contain 30+ images.

I want all the images on one page, no pagination.

Don't need some fancy load-while-scrolling thing. I just want the page to load and the images to load after.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to insert the elements after the pageload, something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = '//domain.tld/image.png';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(image);
}
</script>
```